# List style span and text with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How can I create the list style something like the image blow?

[image]

I wanna push the `span` to the left of the `li` element.

HTML code:

```
<ul>
    <li>test<span>3</span></li>
    <li>foo<span>5</span></li>
    <li>bar<span>4</span></li>
</ul>
```

My current style:

```
ul{  
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

I'm looking for solutions with only `flexbox` and without using `float`.

Comment: Could you tell why float is not an option?

Answer (score 3):

With flexbox and without float.

```css
ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: arial;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    background: #4a90e2;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 6px;
}
ul li {
    background: #285b97;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 5px;
    margin: 5px;
}
span {
    display: flex;
    padding: 3px 6px;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    color: #285b97;
    font-size: 10px;
    align-self: flex-start;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: #acd2ff;
    border-radius: 2px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>test<span>span</span></li>
    <li>foo<span>span</span></li>
    <li>bar<span>span</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display: flex` on `li` and change order of `span` to `-1` so it shows at first element.

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #4A90E2;
  padding: 10px;
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  display: flex;
  background: #285B97;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px
}
span {
  background: #ACD2FF;
  order: -1;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #285B97;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>li<span>span</span></li>
  <li>li<span>span</span></li>
  <li>li<span>span</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set flexbox layout on the `li` tag.

```
li {
  display: flex;                   /* flexbox */
  flex-direction: row-reverse;     /* orders */
  justify-content: space-between;  /* alignments */
}
```

The plain text outside the `span` will be rendered as anonymous flex items.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>a<span>1</span></li>
  <li>b<span>2</span></li>
  <li>c<span>3</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why complicate things when it can be done simple :) ... upvoted